# Android video editor classes

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am trying to create an Android video editing application. I noticed in the SDK sources there are a number of classes in the package 'android.media.videoeditor' that appear to do what I need; however, when I try and import them into my Java project, I can't because according to Eclipse they don't exist! I checked the contents of 'android.jar' and sure enough, the classes are missing.

One of the classes in that package - MediaArtistNativeHelper.java - uses JNI to call out to whatever native methods it needs to, which are implemented in C++ from what I can tell (does this mean I need to build them separately?)

My question is, how can I use these classes in my project?

I am developing the app using Eclipse on a Mac.

Comment: Hey, got any solution ?

Comment: I contacted someone at Google about this and was told to use MediaCodec instead for what I was trying to do. The videoeditor package is hidden because it's not meant to be used. I ended up using MediaCodec and ffmpeg to solve my problem as the Android media package didn't do exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The [android.media.videoeditor](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/media/java/android/media/videoeditor) package is an internal/hidden package**, because the Javadoc above it's classes/interfaces contain the {@hide} or @hide annotation.

**You are not allowed to use it from within your application** and as you saw the API is not present in android.jar which contains the public API's available. 
FYI the package's javadoc can be seen [here](http://developer.oesf.biz/em/developer/reference/eggplant/android/media/videoeditor/package-summary.html).

For adding media functionality to your application use the [android.media package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html) instead, which:

> Provides classes that manage various media interfaces in audio and
>   video.
>
> The Media APIs are used to play and, in some cases, record media
>   files. This includes audio (e.g., play MP3s or other music files,
>   ringtones, game sound effects, or DTMF tones) and video (e.g., play a
>   video streamed over the web or from local storage).
>
> Other special classes in the package offer the ability to detect the
>   faces of people in Bitmaps (FaceDetector), control audio routing (to
>   the device or a headset) and control alerts such as ringtones and
>   phone vibrations (AudioManager).

The contents of the android.jar showing what the android.media package contains:

(Taken from adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platforms/**android-17**/android.jar)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how to use this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/videoeditor/OverlayFrame.java  by using MediaRecorder class available..??

Comment: @Subra Check the android.media package documentation or grab the source code for [platform/frameworks/base](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/) and see in which classes the things from android.media.videoeditor package are used.

Answer (score 0):

Internal and hidden packages can't be accessed at compile time because the android sdk doesn't have them.

There are no easy work around for this. However you can try this tutorial http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-2-hacking-around/

This tutorial explains how to extract the "full" android.jar from a device so that you can get the hidden packages during compile time. Once you have the "hidden" packages at compile time, you can build your app with these. This may sound like a silver bullet but it has major drawbacks. Once you use non-standard APIs all bets are off. If the "hidden" packages were to be changed/modified in future OS upgrades, it would break your product. In production environment this approach is a deal breaker, but for apps developed for personal/academic use, it might be your thing.

Note: I have not personally tried this, but found it sometime back when facing a similar problem to yours (my answer was in some other hidden package).